# Run script in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

can i run a java script in ajax? I've tried to embed some java script on the php that was triggered by an ajax command, the script is intended to change html attribute in the parent page. it doesn't work, when i look at the console  in firebug it only print the script and doesn't even make an alert.

tnx so much for the rplies.

Comment: If you post some code we could try to help you...

Comment: Feel free to include some code that you've tried but isn't working.

Comment: $.ajax({ url:"process.php", data: data_sent,type: "POST" });


i need to get the vaLUE of the variable inside the process.php

tnx.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate the response text.

E.G. returning `alert('foobar')` in the ajax, you can then do `eval(ajaxResponseText)`.

using a library like Prototype.js you can tell it to automatically evaluate script tags within the response text.

Comment: $.ajax({ url:"process.php", data: data_sent,type: "POST",success:function(response){alert(response); }}


is this what you mean?.., it work on echo and alert inside the process.php but how can i get the value of the variable inside the process.php


tnx for the answers

Comment: not sure what you'r asking. please post what `process.php` returns.

Comment: in the process.php, i will query some value, definitely an avatart; the holder of the queried data is $myavatar.., 

$myavatar = quried_avatar;

Answer (score 0):

Doing such thing is considered very bad practice, you really better avoid it.

Instead of having the PHP send raw JS code, have it send "command" or "data" then parse this in the AJAX callback.

For example if you want to show alert have the PHP send only the text to appear in the alert, then in the AJAX callback take this value and do:

```
alert(ajaxResponse);
```